# Manipulating List?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a huge list with 1000 elements. Manually entering  and calculating SUM of probabilities it would take a few hours.

Example:

```
 list = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3}
```

Calculating probabilities:

```
Counts[list]/Length[list]
```

> ```
> <|1 -> 1/6, 2 -> 1/6, 3 -> 1/2, 4 -> 1/6|>
> ```

Calculating the sum of the list elements * probabilities

```
1*(1/6) + 2*(1/6) + 3*(1/2) + 3*(1/2) + 4*(1/6) + 3*(1/2)= 17/3
```

Could you give me some tips please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated as I miss read the question**

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3};
counts= Counts[list]
(* <|1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 1|> *)
```

`Keys[counts]*vals` gives you number of occurrences times the value of the occurrence. Then calculate the product with `Times` on making a pair with this value and its probability. Finally, `Total` the list of results from the multiplication.

```
With[{vals = Values[counts]},
 Total[Times[Sequence @@ #] & /@ 
   Transpose@{Keys[counts]*vals, vals/Length[list]}]
 ]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yours answer is Wrong! Sum is 17/3 not 8/3......

Comment: @Mariusz Updated as I misread the question.

Comment: Yours answer is correct and very speedly.:-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Count` and `Dot` to get `17/3` from your `list`:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3};
Dot[list, Count[list,#]/Length@list&/@list]
(* 17/3 *)
```

Comment: Yours answer is correct :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to see what is happening if you use symbols rather than numbers.

```
list = {a, b, c, c, d, c};

prob = Counts[list]/Length[list];
```

The sum of the product of the elements and their corresponding probabilities is given by either the `Dot` product

```
elem = Union[list];

elem.prob /@ elem // Simplify
```

> 1/6 (a + b + 3 c + d)

or more simply the `Mean`

```
Mean[list]
```

> 1/6 (a + b + 3 c + d)

If you are going to include each individual element in the sum then the probability of each individual element is just `1/Length[list]`

```
Total[list/Length[list]] // Simplify
```

> 1/6 (a + b + 3 c + d)

It is unclear what statistic your calculation represents or to what purpose it would be used.

Comment: .Yours answer is Wrong! Sum is 17/3 not 8/3.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bob said "it is unclear what statistic your calculation represents" ... but maybe you'll be interested in more explicit syntax (see also these [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ProbabilityAndStatistics.html)):

Given your distribution :

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3};
```

then for example, the probability to get 3 is :

```
Probability[x == 3, Distributed[x, list]]
```

> 1/2

Then what you ask for is :

```
list.(Probability[x == #, Distributed[x, list]] & /@ list)
```

> 17/3

but it looked like you were asking for :

```
Expectation[x, Distributed[x, list]]
```

> 8/3

Comment: I wanted to sum ​​it got it 17/3.English is not my native language. While translating I had something to mess with the question.Google Translator ;-)